# Бесконечная сборка проекта в Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Проект отлично работал. После того, как удалил DevExpress 11 и поставил версию 13.2 и вручную удалил ссылки на 11 и добавил на 13.2 версию, проект стал бесконечно собираться. Иногда помогает отмена сборки, а иногда студия зависает и не хочет выключаться никаким способом. В чём может быть причина подобной проблемы? Вот что выдаёт при попытке перестроить(сборку отменил самостоятельно):

1>------ Перестроение всех файлов начато: проект: NagrCheck, Конфигурация: Debug Any CPU ------
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4365,5): error MSB4018: непредвиденная ошибка при выполнении задачи Copy".
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4365,5): error MSB4018: System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: Отменена задача.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4365,5): error MSB4018:    в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4365,5): error MSB4018:    в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4365,5): error MSB4018:    в Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Copy.CopyParallel(CopyFileWithState copyFile, Int32 parallelism, List`1& destinationFilesSuccessfullyCopied)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4365,5): error MSB4018:    в Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Copy.Execute(CopyFileWithState copyFile, Int32 parallelism)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4365,5): error MSB4018:    в Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Copy.Execute()
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4365,5): error MSB4018:    в Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4365,5): error MSB4018:    в Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext()
Сборка была отменена.

Comment: почему бы не удалить полностью утилитой (которая почистит все за прогой) и не поставить заново

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц удалить DevExpress?

Comment: Ну в ней же проблема...